# What's the downside of bolts/screws with self-aligning tips?

Tags: machining

Is there any downside to bolts with self-aligning tips?
Note that there's two types that I'm aware off. One has a sort of square tip protruding from end of the bolt, and the other is like the tip of the bolt has been ground/lathed all around to form a cone-shaped tip at the end.

Are these more prone to starting off out of alignment and so messing up the threads of whatever they're being screwed into?

I'm just wondering for tricky situations - like blind holes where you're just fishing around with your hands can't really see if things are perfectly aligned or not, or cases where you have a captive nut on one side that can slide around before the bolt catches it... I rarely see auto manufacturers use these sorts of bolts / screws, and I'm wondering why.